# How do I "legally" fade out the navigation bar in an app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

It seems the only way to remove a navigation bar with animation is via it sliding upward. I want it to fade, like in Photos.app.

It would be easiest to change the alpha, however [Apple's guidelines state](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html):

> Prior to iOS v5.0, when used in conjunction with a navigation
>   controller, there are only a handful of direct customizations you can
>   make to the navigation bar. Specifically, it is alright to modify the
>   barStyle, tintColor, and translucent properties, but you must never
>   directly change UIView-level properties such as the frame, bounds,
>   alpha, or hidden properties directly.

The language is a little weird, as it states prior to iOS 5, but it stated you're not allowed to change the alpha value directly, and it never states you're allowed to now.

I don't want my app to get rejected.

How do I fade out the navigation bar like I would the status bar?

Comment: Hmmmm ... How can it be OK to "modify the [...] translucent properties" but "never directly change [...] alpha ..."??? How to change the translucency *without* changing the alpha???

Comment: Agreed, I'm equally confused. EDIT: There is a 'translucent' property that you're allowed to access, but it's simply YES or NO, and set to YES isn't fully transparent.

Comment: I'd take that "you must never..." as a warning that something will break if you try, not as a threat of rejection. App Store rejection might happen too, but more likely due to your app being broken than as punishment for not heeding the warning.

Comment: why'd you mark my answer correct and give the bounty to someone else?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This was a fun one to solve.

It should have been very straight-forward:  use `UIView transitionWithView` to perform a cross-fade between the hidden and non-hidden states of the navigation bar, as set by the public API `setNavigationBarHidden:animated:`.  In fact this works for "fading out" the navbar, but fading it back in had an issue.  The issue was that the navbar would slide into place regardless of the fact that `UIView +transitionWithView:` doesn't animate animatable properties (e.g. `frame`) unless you specify `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent`.

To me this says that internally the `UINavigationController` repositions the `UINavigationBar` inside an animation block regardless of whether animating was specified in the call to `setNavigationBarHidden:animated:`.  The duration for this animation block is probably set to '0' when `animate:` is set to `NO`.

The solution is to set the navigation bar visible (sans animation) before the cross-fade transition.  This ensures that the navigation bar begins the cross-fade in the correct position, and that the cross-fade will only reveal the new non-hidden state.

My sample project is a standard Single View Application.  On the storyboard is a `UINavigationController`, which is the entry point.  I set the bar style for this controller's `UINavigationBar` to black-translucent (similar to the Photos app).   The navigation controller's `rootViewController` is a simple `UIViewController` with a `UIImageView` filling the entire bounds (also like the Photos app).  I added a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on the view to invoke the following code, in the view controller:

```
- (IBAction) onShowHideNavbar: (id) sender
{
    BOOL hide = !self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden;

    if ( !hide)
    {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: hide animated: NO];
    }

    [UIView transitionWithView: self.navigationController.view
                      duration: 1
                       options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations: ^{

                        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: hide animated: NO];
                    }
                    completion: nil ];
}
```

All this said, I don't think you'd get into any trouble (Apple Rejection) for messing with the hidden or alpha properties of the `UINavigationBar` directly.  The docs warn against touching these because they're managed by the UINavigationController and changing them might have unseen consequences.  But In My Opinion they're public APIs and as such using them shouldn't be cause for rejection.

Comment: When you show-hide the navigation bar on UINavigationController, the content view frame changes. So, the main controller is resized. If you use this code, you will have two problems: first, you will see a black background behind the navigation bar until the animation ends (if you used an image with black borders, like photos.app,  you probably didn't see it). Second: after the animation has finished, the main view will resize itself automatically without animation, with a jump. Not so good. There are problem even during fade in, look here: [link]( http://youtu.be/jdChWTkPGGw)

Comment: yes, you'll get the jump with an opaque navbar.  if you set the navbar to be translucent black (as I said in the answer) it won't jump because the content view will already be behind it.  if you need the capability with a fully opaque bar then more work is needed.

Comment: You are right, my mistake. When you use the translucent bar, the view extends under the navbar, so no "jump" in the animation. With opaque bar the trick should be wantsFullScreenLayout as you suggested in chat, but for some reason I'm not able to get it working

Answer (score 6):

You can't animate properties of the navigation bar of a UINavigationController legally.
However, you can show a navigation controller with hidden navigation bar (hiding it always or only on a specific view controller, as you prefer), and replace it with your "special" instance of `UINavigationBar` ;-)

I attach a sample project (I used an Xcode template to create it faster): [FakeNavBar](http://www.lombax.it/Documents/FakeNavBar.zip)

Look at the `viewDidLoad` method of the `DetailViewController`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self configureView];

    self.fakeBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds];


    UIBarButtonItem *back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(back)];



    UINavigationItem *backItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back"];
    backItem.leftBarButtonItem = back;
    [self.fakeBar pushNavigationItem:backItem animated:YES];

    [self.view addSubview:self.fakeBar];

}
```

Here's a video of the final product [on YouTube](http://youtu.be/oPkJbN0R9Cw).

Comment: Now *this* is cool. I'll check it out when I get home, thank you.

Comment: An obvious issue with this is your fake 'back' button isn't styled as a back button (no left-pointy arrow).  You'd also have to jump through a bunch of hoops if you make use of standard UIViewController navigationItem properties (e.g. you set them in a nib/storyboard).  I'm not a fan of reinventing the wheel in this way.

Comment: @TomSwift , first of all, if the downvote is your, I expect that with such reputation you know that downvotes should be given for incorrect answers, and not for the answers you don't like. Now, talking about the answer, the back button is not an issue: since explainig how stacks of navigation items works wasn't the goal of the answer, I preferred to focus on the main question only. To prevent this "issue", it's sufficient to add a stack of navigation items to have the normal arrow as your back button. Moreover, (continue in the next comment)

Comment: There is no reason to "jump through a bunch of hoops" if you know and understand *strongly* how things works in this case. You can, for example, put all the code in a superclass and, moreover, copy the navigation items of the original nav controller. Check this last example (again: 5 minutes code, and now you can set titles or additional buttons in the nib):  [link](http://www.lombax.it/Documents/FakeNavBar2.zip) (use the superclass only on VC where you want to enable the special behavior, this will work even with longer navigation stacks, obviously with some debug)

Comment: exactly.  sounds like a bunch of hoop-jumping to me. ;)

Comment: @LombaX.  BTW, I do feel your answer is incorrect because of the first statement, which is false.

Comment: A strange point of view, because Apple is clear: you must never change its frame, bounds, or alpha values directly. When I say "fade the bar" obviously I mean the bar itself directly, in your example you fade the entire view which is different. Do you think that Apple official documentation is not enough to say that the first statement is correct?

Answer (score 2):

A way around this (I don't know exactly how you are planning to animate to the next view or in what way you want to incorporate the fade) is to render the current view to a uiimage, make a full screen UIImageView with this image (basically replacing your existing UIView with a picture of it) Swap in your new view behind the image view and then fade out the image view.

You can also crop out just the UInavigationBar part of the image and fade that after the transition. This way you can apply any image effects to the 'UINavgationBar' without getting rejected by apple.

Comment: Sadly, in an apple controlled world, tricks like this are often the only way to get certain effects. There may well be a better way, i'm only giving you an idea if you don't find another one.

Comment: There is a new "snapshot" support in UIView (that just changed in b4) that might help?

Comment: Unfortunately I need for things to happen in the UIView while the fade occurs, so a static image wouldn't work anyway. And verec, it has to work with iOS 6 for the time being unfortunately.

Comment: He can simply use a custom navigation bar instead of the one provided by nav controller, it's so simple...Doug, look at my answer ;-)

Comment: Nicely done LombaX, this is the better way I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1):

I know of no Apple-sanctioned way to do this.  I doubt you would be rejected for modifying the alpha value of the navigationBar, but like you, I don't know for certain.

You can of course implement your own navigation controller/navigation bar with which you can do anything you want.  That is what I have done in my applications when I need to do something like this.  Apple has been totally fine with that.  Bonus points: Apple can change their controls as much as they want without breaking your layout if you use custom controls.  This was recently a problem in certain areas of our application where the app looks VASTLY different in different versions of iOS (7).

Anyway, that's my 2 cents...

Answer (score 0):

If you keep reading, this is the next paragraph right after your quote:

> In iOS v5.0 and later, you can customize the appearance of the bar
>   using the methods listed in “Customizing the Bar Appearance.” You can
>   customize the appearance of all navigation bars using the appearance
>   proxy ([UINavigationBar appearance]), or just of a single bar.

Clicking the link (Customizing the Bar Appearance) will show you this:

> **Customizing the Bar Appearance**
>     tintColor  *property*
>   – backgroundImageForBarMetrics:
>   – setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:
>   – titleVerticalPositionAdjustmentForBarMetrics:
>   – setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:forBarMetrics:
>    titleTextAttributes  *property*

So in iOS v5.0 and later, that is the list that you can (legally) change.  You might be able to play some games with the alpha of the tintColor or a background image in order to make it look like it is fading out (and then hide it) but I doubt that it will look quite right.  Probably worth an attempt though.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to easily fade the navigation bar, but you *can* easily fade *a picture* of the navigation bar. So one thing you could do is to create an image of the nav bar, replace the nav bar with your image, and then animate the image view with alpha going to 0. Or you could do the opposite: position an image view on top of the nav bar, and *fade in* an image of whatever is supposed to be behind the nav bar.