# Xcode: Animate UINavigationBar titleView's alpha property

Tags: ios, objective-c

**Scenario**

I have an app that uses a `UITableViewController`. When the user `scrolls` up or down, I detect the `scroll` using the follow code:

```
-(void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    CGPoint currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;

    if (currentOffset.y > lastCurrentOffset.y) {
        NSLog(@"Down");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"up");
    }

    lastCurrentOffset = currentOffset;
}
```

From this code I call a method that regulates the height of the `navigation bar`.

Once the bar is beginning to animate upward and "hiding itself", I would like the `titleView` property of the `navigation bar` to fade out.

**Question**

Does anyone know how to animate the `titleView's` alpha property when the navigation bar hides itself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I "legally" fade out the navigation bar in an app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913669/how-do-i-legally-fade-out-the-navigation-bar-in-an-app)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26365491/1418457